# how to load xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, url

Can any one give me a proper explain why i am unable to get updated XML content from URL. I have a XML file which will frequently update. But in my application i am getting old data. Until i restart my application.

Here i am placing my code that i have tried

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();;
string str;
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    str = wc.DownloadString(location.AbsoluteUri);
}
doc.LoadXml(str);
```

And also tried with below code

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("url");
using (Stream stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    xmldoc.Load(stream);
}
```

Comment: is it a webservice based on wsdl?

Comment: I was using it in WPF application. I tried in console application as well. But got same problem

Comment: i mean the xml file you are trying to parse is it a webservice ?

Comment: Yes...It is a web service but currently i am testing it from github raw file.

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that raw git hub take time to update in all servers so it is taking time to update. So you can use other web services to get result you want.